# subprocess.Popen robocopy doesn't work when args are a sequence

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, robocopy

I'm trying to Popen robocopy with subprocess on Win10 with Python 3.9.

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831998/subprocess-calledprocesserror-when-running-robocopy-from-python-3-on-windows-7) that `shell=True` is needed when the arguments are not split and `shell=False` if they are but whatever i try, splitted arguments always result in errorcode 16 for me and passing the arguments as a single string doesn't seem to care about the shell parameter and always works.

Here's the most important fragment of testcode:

```
tmpdir = tempfile.gettempdir()

srcdir = f'{tmpdir}\\tstsrc'
try: os.mkdir(srcdir)
except FileExistsError: pass
Path(f'{srcdir}\\test.txt').touch()

dstdir = f'{tmpdir}\\tstdst'

def testRobocopy(args, shell=False, expectedReturncode=0):
    # args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor
    assert(isinstance(args, list) or isinstance(args, str))
    shutil.rmtree(dstdir, ignore_errors=True)
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=shell)
    p.wait()
    assert(p.returncode == expectedReturncode)
    
# all of the following set returncode=16 (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.)
testRobocopy(['Robocopy', f'"{srcdir}"', f'"{dstdir}"'], shell=False, expectedReturncode=16)
testRobocopy(['Robocopy', f'"{srcdir}"', f'"{dstdir}"'], shell=True, expectedReturncode=16)

# all of the following set returncode=1 (success)
testRobocopy(f'Robocopy "{srcdir}" "{dstdir}"', shell=False, expectedReturncode=1)
testRobocopy(f'Robocopy "{srcdir}" "{dstdir}"', shell=True, expectedReturncode=1)
```

The full testcode can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/GhnxbM)

How can i Popen robocopy with splitted parameters?

Comment: I guess the problem might be with the repeated quotes. Try `f'{srcdir}'` instead of `f'"{srcdir}"'` etc., otherwise Robocopy is receiving `"c:\path\to\file"` (with the quotes) which perhaps it doesn't strip away.

Comment: @Czaporka Thats it! Thanks a lot. If you add this as an answer i can accept it. Looks like subprocess insists of adding them itself when passing args in a list. I guess i'm just too used to put everything in quotes because of possible whitespaces. Tbh, i'd expected a note in the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) but i couldn't find any.

Comment: No, `subprocess` doesn't add any quotes. When you're executing something from shell and put quotes around the arguments, the quotes are for the shell so it knows that whitespace inside the quotes belongs to the argument and it shouldn't interpret it. But if you're executing a subprocess directly from your own application, you typically pass a list/array of strings representing the program and arguments, and that goes straight to the OS, not through any shell that would strip away quotes or handle pipes or output redirection - every character ultimately arrives at the process's argument list.

Comment: @Czaporka I've read in the docs that "On Windows, if args is a sequence, it will be converted to a string in a manner described in Converting an argument sequence to a string on Windows. This is because the underlying CreateProcess() operates on strings.". CreateProcess needs the quotes for the program and the program might need them to parse the args correctly. I'd had to investigate more but i often use CreateProcess and never had luck without quoting stuff.

Comment: Okay apologies, I'm not too familiar with how these things work on Windows. In this case I guess you're right that `subprocess` adds the quotes under the hood. But ultimately the way you should call `Popen` on either OS looks consistent - superfluous quotation marks will become part of the argument string.

Comment: @Czaporka Here's a C++ example for reference: https://rextester.com/JKHZP8961 . I'm just starting with python and it seems i'm not used yet to all this automatisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeated quotation marks are the problem: when specifying the command as a list, arguments should be `f'{srcdir}'` etc. rather than `f'"{srcdir}"'`, otherwise Robocopy is receiving `"c:\path\to\file"` (with the quotes) which perhaps it doesn't know to strip away.
When the command is passed as a string, the quotation marks are evaluated and stripped away by the shell.